# Hadoop: dfs is deprecated but hdfs class not found

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to Hadoop, and am trying to check what data is available in HDFS. However, the `dfs` command returns a response that indicates the class is deprecated, and that hdfs should be used:

```
-bash-4.2$ hadoop dfs -ls
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

ls: `.': No such file or directory
```

When I try the `hdfs` command, though, I get what appears to be a Java class lookup error:

```
-bash-4.2$ hadoop hdfs -ls
Error: Could not find or load main class hdfs
```

Is there something wrong with my Hadoop setup, or have others encountered this catch-22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `hadoop fs` or `hdfs dfs`, then `-ls`

You can run `hdfs dfs -ls /` to check the root of HDFS, but you will get `.: No such file or directory` because the output of `echo "hdfs:///user/$(whoami)"` does not exist yet, and you need to make it using `hadoop fs -mkdir -p hdfs:///user/$(whoami)`.

That command must be repeated for every user account that attempts to access their HDFS user directory